# Multiple Ajax Call parameters all coming as null in .Net Core Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I know this question has been asked several times here, but none of the answers are working for me. I am trying everything since last 3 hours.

**Requirement is simple**: Call a .Net Core 2.1 Controller method from View using JQuery. Pass 3 parameters to controller.

**My jQuery:**

```
function EmpSubmit() {
    var EmpName = $('#txtEmpName').val();
    var EmpDesignation = $('#txtDesignation').val();
    var EmpCity = $('#txtCity').val();

    // ajax call to create new employee

    var data1 = '{"EmpName": "' + EmpName + '", "EmpDesignation" : "' + EmpDesignation + '", "EmpCity" : "' + EmpCity + '"}';
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Employee/CreateViaModal/")',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data1,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {

            $("#EmpCreateModal").modal('hide');
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    });
}
```

**The Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateViaModal(string EmpName, string EmpDesignation, string EmpCity)
    {
        TblEmployee tblEmployee = new TblEmployee();
        tblEmployee.EmpName = EmpName;
        tblEmployee.Designation = EmpDesignation;
        tblEmployee.City = EmpCity;

        _context.Add(tblEmployee);
       _context.SaveChanges();

        return Json(tblEmployee);
    }
```

The Ajax call is hitting the debugger in the controller successfully, just the parameters are coming as NULL all the time. Not sure what needs to be done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are sending a string to your action.

Replace `var data1 = '{"EmpName": "' + EmpName + '", "EmpDesignation" : "' + EmpDesignation + '", "EmpCity" : "' + EmpCity + '"}';` with

```
var data1 = {
    EmpName,
    EmpDesignation,
    EmpCity
}
```

and in your AJAX request:
`data: JSON.stringify(data1)` instead of `data: data1,`

After that, create a `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
  public string EmpName {get;set;}
  public string EmpDesignation {get;set;}
  public string EmpCity {get;set;}
}
```

and change your action method to:

`public IActionResult CreateViaModal([FromBody]Employee employee)`

Comment: @BuggyCoder did you add `JSON.stringify(data1)`?